# my basic 'guess the number program', it will not acknowledge 'a correct guess to the computer's number'

Tags: python, python-3.4

I made a simple guess the number program, in my quest to learn python! lol

however, the computer will not acknowledge the user's guess was correct, and it will always go to the "incorrect", even though the computers number displays as the users guess. My code seems correct, so i am at a loss. Any help is appreciated!

```
def randomNumGen():
    userGuess = input('The Computer has thought of a number between 1-5, deposit    your guess now!: ')

    if finalValue == userGuess:
        print("You've guessed correctly!, Very lucky you are!")

    else:
        print("You're guess was incorrect, try again please")
        print("The computer's guess was",finalValue)
        main()
```

EDIT:

the output looks like this, which explains the obvious issue here:

```
>The Computer has thought of a number between 1-5, deposit your guess now!: 2
>You're guess was was incorrect 
>The computer's guess was 2
```

so the 'computer' will not recognize a correct guess when one has been given.

Comment: Okay. So what's the problem?

Comment: the program always says the user's guess was incorrect.

Comment: i'd appreciate any help here. I feels as though i am specific enough for you guys to provide me a quick answer. Here is the output, showing the obvious issue with the program:    deposit your guess: 2    ,  You're guess was incorrect , the computer's guess was 2 . So obviously the program will not recognize a correct a guess by the user.

Comment: You should add appropriate tags to let the people expert in that particular field see your question. Also, don't post the extra information in the comment. Edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: finalValue and userGuess are of different types. make sure they are both numbers or both strings beforehand.

Comment: From what I see here, I would assume that `finalValue` is an `int`, while `userGuess` is a string, as that is the return type of `input`

Comment: I am new to the forum, so thanks for the tips. I have added a generic 'python' tag on top of my python 3.4 one, and updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `finalValue` is an integer, while the input from `input()` will be a string. You should make both into strings, or both into integers before you compare them.

To convert an integer to a string, you can simply do this:

```
my_string = str(my_integer)
```

This will take an integer named `my_integer` and return a string which will be assigned to be `my_string`

```
def randomNumGen():
    userGuess = input('The Computer has thought of a number between 1-5, deposit    your guess now!: ')

    if str(finalValue) == userGuess:
        print("You've guessed correctly!, Very lucky you are!")

    else:
        print("You're guess was incorrect, try again please")
        print("The computer's guess was",finalValue)
        main()
```

This is the simplest change I can see that will make this work. Note the line:

```
if str(finalValue) == userGuess:
```

I am comparing `finalValue` cast into a string with the `userGuess`.

Comment: i am not sure if i am understanding you correctly, however, the issue persists. I added 'userGuess = str(finalValue)' directly under where userGuess is defined. I have no errors also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your input is being processed as a string when it needs to be recognized as an integer. Try this:

```
def randomNumGen():
userGuess = input('The Computer has thought of a number between 1-5,     deposit    your guess now!: ')
userGuess = int(userGuess)

if finalValue == userGuess:
    print("You've guessed correctly!, Very lucky you are!")

else:
    print("You're guess was incorrect, try again please")
    print("The computer's guess was",finalValue)
    main()
```